# Will AcquireTokenSilentAsync not work after 90 days?

Tags: azure, authentication, adal

I'm building an ASP.NET Web API service which connects to Azure Graph API to get a list of users. 
So my scenario is to create an MVC page on this service => let Azure AD admin login and grant permission => cache access_token and use this to call API.

However, I acknowledged that access_token will be expired after 1 hour. Even if it's renewed by using refresh_token, admin will actually have to manually sign in on this service again after 90 days.

I read on some example which use AcquireTokenSilentAsync method from ADAL library. But not sure if it would be useless after 90 days ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, currently the Access Token will expire within the hour. The Refresh Token will be valid for 14 days, and can be used to obtain a new Access Token and a new Refresh Token. You can carry on doing this for up to 90 days. (Note that these are the current values, they may change in the future.) `AcquireTokenSilent` and `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` will attempt to use existing state (i.e. Refresh Tokens, if available) to obtain a new Access Token, or throw an exception if this is not possible.

That said, I suspect that is probably not the best approach for your scenario. It sounds like you are in one of two situations:

1. You are building a middleware service (an API) that will be used by a different app which is accessed by authenticated users. If this is the case, you can use on-behalf-of flow, where (a) your middleware service is registered as a web app/API in Azure AD, (b) the user-facing client app and obtains an Access Token (for the current user) to the middleware API, and (c) the middleware API uses that Access Token to obtain a new Access Token to the Azure AD Graph API, on behalf of the original user.

   - Sample: [active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof)
2. You just need to enable unattended access to the Graph API. If the middleware service is a highly-trusted environment, you can use app-only authentication (also known as "headless", or "daemon" apps) to obtain an Access Token without any user context. (This is the Client Credentials Grant OAuth 2.0 flow.)

   - Sample: [active-directory-dotnet-daemon-certificate-credential](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-certificate-credential)
   - Sample: [active-directory-dotnet-daemon](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon)

Comment: I used to try the daemon app but was not successful. The token returned still gave me 401 unauthorized. Will give it a try again. But this solution won't face the 90-day issue, right?

Comment: In option (2) with app creds, you can always re-authenticate without the user involved (since its credential flow) and continue calling graph resource without user knowing you re-authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by default refresh tokens expire in 14 days (access tokens in an hour) but with some configuration I believe it can go until 90 days. This is for security reasons and a good practice. Nothing wrong with it. However, this will only work if you implement your own cache because by default ADAL cache uses memory and upon restart it will lose those tokens.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect

Comment: So I'm developing a middle ware service which pull the list of users from AD and then returns it to client via REST API. What is the best way to keep the middle ware connected to Azure Graph API consistently without having to let admin sign in again every 90 days

Comment: Are the users of the application that uses the middleware authenticated (with Azure AD)?

Comment: They are SharePoint online user and I'm gonna make the client to be a SharePoint-hosted add-in. So those users are also authenticated via Azure AD right? Or via SharePoint online itself?